# How to sort combination of string and number in datatable

Tags: html, datatables, thymeleaf

Below is the code to display search results as a table.

HTML :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link th:href="@{/css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css}" rel=" stylesheet" />
<link th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.css}" rel=" stylesheet" />
<link th:href="@{/css/jquery.dataTables.css}" rel=" stylesheet" />
<link th:href="@{/css/rowReorder.dataTables.css}" rel=" stylesheet" /> 
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.dataTables.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery-ui.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
var table = $("#results").dataTable(
                {
                    "scrollX" : true,
                    "ordering" : true,
                    "order" :
                    [
                        [
                                0, "asc"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "columnDefs" :
                    [
                        {
                            "orderable" : false,
                            "targets" : 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "info" : true,
                });
                });
</script>


<table id="results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID </th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="map : ${searchList}">
            <td>
                <a th:id="${map['ID1']} + 'v' + ${map['ID2']}" style="cursor: pointer;" th:text="${map['ID1']} + ' v ' + ${map['ID2']}"></a>
            </td>
            <td th:text="${map['NAME']}"></td> 
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT :

```
ID         Name 
-----------------
1 v 1      John
121 v 1    Janet
2 v 1      Jack
```

The above output sorts in a 121 before 2 because "v" is added in the middle .

But the expected output is :

```
ID         Name 
-----------------
1 v 1      John
2 v 1      Jack
121 v 1    Janet
```

Can anyone help on this issue please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me. I added a hidden column to display ID1 + ID2 (Without v in the middle.) And also added a script in dataTable configuration.

```
'columnDefs': [
    { 'orderData':[2], 'targets': [1] },
    {
        'targets': [2],
        'visible': false,
        'searchable': false
    },
],
```

So when the user sort column 1 (ID1 v ID2), it will actually sort column 2(ID1ID2)

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom sort plugin for that. It seems to me that you want to sort on the first ID, so

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "first-id-pre": function ( a ) {
        return parseInt($(a).text().split(' ')[0]);
    },

    "first-id-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "fist-id-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

usage :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs : [
     { type: 'first-id', targets: 0 }
  ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jt66jf42/**

Comment: Thakyou so much. I tried your suggestion. But it doesnt work. I have added `"columnDefs" : [
                             { type: 'first-id', targets: 0 }
                          ]`  to other existing attributes. I have also updated my question. Can you tell what is wrong it the code. Thanks again.

Comment: @Java_User, it did not work as "copy paste"-work because you are wrapping the content into an `<a>` tag. But see update, have taken care of that - also in the fiddle.  And to be clear, `targets` is the column-index, if the column is another than the first, then `targets` should of course be set to that columns index. You can set multiple `targets` with `[0, 4, 7]`. Also, the custom sorting plugin should declared _before_ you initalise the dataTable, as in the fiddle.

Comment: Thankyou for the help. Thanks for additional information too. But I got the solution with out  custom sort plugin.

Comment: @Java_User, OK, great - but think it is a little bit overkill with a hidden column just for sorting :) You concatenate the numbers? If `ID2` always is 1 then there will be no problem, but what if `ID2` is `10`? Then `2 v 1` will be considered lower than `1 v 10`, `21` vs `110`..? Anyway +1, and remember to mark your own question as accepted.

Comment: @davidkonard. ID2 have maximum value as 9. It's always single digit. So should not be a problem. I will mark the question as accepted. Thanks for the help .